# How to copy a file from a remote server to a local machine?

Tags: scp, cp

In my terminal shell, I ssh'ed into a remote server, and I `cd` to the directory I want.

Now in this directory, there is a file called `table` that I want to copy to my local machine `/home/me/Desktop`.

How can I do this?

I tried `scp table /home/me/Desktop` but it gave an error about no such file or directory.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you find yourself copying with scp often, you can mount the remote directory in your file browser and drag-and-drop. On my Ubuntu 15 host, it's under the menu bar "Go" > "Enter Location" > `debian@10.42.4.66:/home/debian`. Alternatively, one can use `sshfs` to mount the remote machine's filesystem on the host. But that setup is a little more involved.

Comment: Give `rsync` a try. It's great both for local and remote copies, gives you copy progress, etc. An [example](https://github.com/faif/shell-utils/blob/master/shell-utils.sh#L426)

Answer (score 789, accepted):

The syntax for `scp` is:

If you are on the computer from which you want to send file to a remote computer:

```
scp /file/to/send username@remote:/where/to/put
```

Here the `remote` can be a FQDN or an IP address.

On the other hand if you are on the computer wanting to receive file from a remote computer:

```
scp username@remote:/file/to/send /where/to/put
```

`scp` can also send files between two remote hosts:

```
scp username@remote_1:/file/to/send username@remote_2:/where/to/put
```

So the basic syntax is:

```
scp username@source:/location/to/file username@destination:/where/to/put
```

You can read [`man scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) to get more ideas on this.

Comment: What if I want to copy multiple files?  I added a space and just used another  ```/file/to/send``` Thanks for your awesome answer!

Comment: `scp -r` will copy recursively.

Comment: What i want to copy the files from network to my VM ...how to achieve the same using scp

Comment: @heemayl +1 for the good answer. Thought to add that in the case that it is a secure connection (that requires an authentication) you can use the following (for copying file from local to remote): 
scp -i mykey.pem somefile.txt root@remotehost.ip.address:/some/folder/in/remote

Comment: Use `scp -P 123` to specify custom port

Comment: If i have an ssh session active, then i have to exit ssh session to scp from remote to local. is there any other way?

Comment: [Here's a brief video showing the process](https://youtu.be/8eyfmp7dtYk), including the bit about the secure connection.

Comment: what if we require to login to ssh by .pem file, is there a way to copy file while we stay inside the connection as i'll be able to do it as sudo

Comment: This doesn't cover the case mentioned in the question, where you are ssh'd into a remote server and want to copy a file from that remote server to a local machine. Neither does the video mentioned in [this previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-machine#comment994329_188289). How can one use scp or rsync when already ssh'd into a remote server?

Answer (score 26):

You can use `rsync` as an alternative. It is mainly for syncing files.. but you can use it for this purpose as well.

```
rsync -avzh --stats --progress remoteuser@remoteip:/path/  localpath
```

to add ssh options:

```
rsync -e "ssh -P $port_value" remoteuser@remoteip:/path/  localpath
```

`--progress` and `--stats` are useful for real-time display of transfer.

I think it a better option then SCP, since it skips already transferred files, which is noticeable when you're copy-ing lot of files.

Comment: What if the remoteip is in a network?

Answer (score 25):

```
scp root@10.240.179.4:/root/Jmeter/reports.jtl Downloads/
```

Answer (score 14):

```
scp username@ipaddress:pathtofile localsystempath

scp sadananad@ipaddress:/home/demo/public_html/myproject.tar.gz .
```

If your using with port:

```
scp -Pportnumber username@ipaddress:pathtofile localsystempath 

scp -P2233 sadananad@ipaddress:/home/demo/public_html/myproject.tar.gz .
```

Comment: This will copy the file to the same remote directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you completely trust everyone in the network and you can connect a port of the destination machine directly, you can use netcat: `nc`.

Let's say the IP address of the destination machine is 192.168.1.123

On the destination run:

```
nc -l -p 7777 0.0.0.0 | tar zxvf - -C dest_dir
```

You can choose a different port, and also bind to another IP of your interfaces, 0.0.0.0 just catches on all interfaces.

On the source run:

```
tar zcvf - filename | nc 192.168.1.123 7777
```

IMHO, this is the fastest possible way to send a file from one computer to another using digital networks.

The arguments and command line options might slightly change between different versions of `nc` and `tar`, but it will definitely work with recent Linux distributions.

Comment: I think your tar parameters are wrong, the source should not have "x" and could use "v" as well, for parity.

Comment: @MattesD: Thank you, you are right, fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, to copy a folder and its content from the user (root in this example) directory, to a folder in the local user directory, I run this command on the local machine:

scp -r root@178.62.54.83:~/folderinremoteuserdir ~/folderinlocaluserdir

Note the ~/ which I often seem to forget...