# Fail to scp file from remote to local

Tags: centos, osx

I  read series of instructions and answers about scp

[Example syntax for Secure Copy (scp)](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

[scp - How to copy a file from a remote server to a local machine? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-machine)

but I cannot apply it correclty

```
$ pwd
#the local path on local machine
pwd
/Users/me/PubRepo/bash
```

When I tried to scp a file from remote to the local

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# echo "scp test message" > a_test_file.md
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# cat a_test_file.md
scp test message
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# pwd
/root
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# scp root@icodehero.com:a_test_file.md  .
root@icodehero.com's password: 
a_test_file.md                                                                  100%   17     3.6KB/s   00:00    
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]#
```

it indicate success to transfer, but I did not find it locally

```
ls | grep "a_test_file.md"
#does not return
```

additionally it does not exist anywhere locally

```
find / -name "a_test_file.md" 2>/dev/null                                                              
## no match
```

What's the problem with my usage?

Comment: Are you intentionally prefixing your ls and find commands with a history recall mark, `!` ?

Comment: I removed them, it's a shortcut to apply commands within IPython console. @JeffSchaller

Comment: You created a file `a_test_file.md` on `iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z` then copied a file with identical name from `icodehero.com` to `iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z` and after this operation `a_test_file.md` doesn't exist on `iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z`???

Comment: No, I scp it to the local  `scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory`

Comment: Oh, I got your idea, I should do it on local machine @jimmij

Comment: “does not return” or “returns nothing”?

Comment: It is hard to follow what you are doing (Which machine is which). But on `iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z` you create a file, then copy a file with the same name, from `icodehero.com`, over the top of the file that you just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your console log it looks like you call `scp` on the remote host where `a_test_file.md` is created, but you use `.` as the second parameter, which is the *destination*. The call always has the source first and the destination after. Like @jimmij mentioned in the comments, this would copy another file with identical name from another remote.

So you have two possibilities:

1. Call `scp` from the machine where the file should end up (your local machine). Assuming `icodehero.com` is your remote machine, the `scp` call you used is correct, just on the wrong machine.
2. Change the `scp` call to `scp a_test_file.md user@your_local_machine:.`, which is only possible if the remote can also access your local machine via ssh.

---

If you are wondering, why the copying was displayed as successful, I assume `icodehero.com` is the machine, on which you created the file, in which case your remote copied the file from itself (which overwrites the file with itself, effectively doing nothing).