# Moving a file from local drive to a remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, file-copy

I'd like to move a folder that contains multiple files within it from my local folder to a ssh user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx machine's temp drive. What would be the best method in doing this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188285/125535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to be able to `ssh` as a user who has write permissions to that system's `/tmp` directory or wherever you are trying to copy the filed. Assuming that you can:

```
rsync -avhH /directory/to/copy user@system:/tmp

scp -r /directory/to/copy user@system:/tmp
```

If the user can't write to the directory, assuming it's `/tmp`, you can create a directory for the user in `/tmp` with (althout `/tmp` is normally world writable but in case it isn't for some reason on your system):

```
mkdir /tmp/directory
```

And then give write permissions by making the user the owner:

```
chown username /tmp/directory
```

After that, the you can use the `rsync` or `scp` commands above.

Comment: Thanks, Nasir.  The folder is located on my desktop within a folder e.g. desktop/configuration - base. so the path would be something like this:  sudo scp -r  /desktop/configuration - base/<folder name with files> user@system:/tmp. is that correct?

Comment: @itsmevic Yes. You need to put quotes around the folder that you are copying because it has spaces. `sudo scp -r "/desktop/configuration - base/<folder name with files>" user@system:/tmp`.